# VBA Excel Макрос поиска

Tags: vba, excel

Нужна помощь в написании макроса для Excel:

Есть ячейки, значение которых - текст, эти значения взяты с другого файла. Нужно организовать поиск этого текста в базе данных (этот текст - название товара), после чего вывести опеределенные значения.

Иное обьяснение. Ячейка А1=А1 (с другого файла, а именно, название товара), в нашем файле, автоматически происходит поиск этого названия и вставляются ингридиенты в определенные ячейки.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что задача примерно следующая:
Есть большой каталог товаров, где указано имя, характеристики и тд.
Есть таблица с неким перечнем товаров, где указаны только имена. Нужно из каталога подтянуть характеристики, при совпадении имен товаров. Это лучше всего делать макросом. Особенно учитывая, что имена товаров могут быть записаны не совсем верно.

Answer (score 5):

Без примера трудно советовать.

Создать массив, пройтись по нему циклом...

Может, ну его, макрос? :)

```
=ВПР(A1;диапазон_другой_книги;столбец_поиска;)
```

Answer (score 3):

1. ВПР и СУММЕСЛИ на другую книгу при большом объеме данных - это зло. Оптимальный вариант написать запрос на лист с товаром и разместить результат в отдельном листе. Выйдет так, что как минимум ВПР будет на другой лист этой же книги.
2. Может быть ВПР, а может лучше использовать Find.